# JTextArea Do not scrollRectToVisible after Re-set Text

Tags: scroll, replace, jtextarea

I encounter a strange issue.
The scenario is that I need to replace a keyword in `JTextArea` with another word.
I have two buttons, one is to find the keyword, and the other is to replace the keyword.
For both buttons, I add the mouse listener and implement function `mouseClicked`. At current stage I can highlight the found keyword and scroll to the keyword position. But when dealing with replace button, after re-setting text, the `JTextArea` always scrolls down to the bottom, but I want to keep the position where the replacement happens, what should I do? Below is my code snippet, but it doesn't work.

```
replaceBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        String keyword = jKeyword.getText();
        if (keyword.length() == 0)
            return;

        String text = jTextArea.getText();
        pos = text.indexOf(keyword, 0);
        if (pos == -1) {
            pos = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "can not find " + keyword);
            return;
        }

        jTextArea.setText(text.replaceFirst(keyword, jReplaceKW.getText()));
        //jTextArea.revalidate();

        //scroll to first keyword occurrence
        try {
            Rectangle rectangle = jTextArea.modelToView(pos);
            jTextArea.scrollRectToVisible(rectangle);
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: set text in function `mousePressed` then scroll in function `mouseReleased`.
I suspect the text has to be represented in the GUI before the component can figure out the scroll dimension? Not sure.

```
replaceBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        String keyword = jKeyword.getText();
        if (keyword.length() == 0)
            return;

        String text = jTextArea.getText();
        pos = text.indexOf(keyword, 0);
        if (pos == -1) {
            pos = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "can not find " + keyword);
            return;
        }

        jTextArea.setText(text.replaceFirst(keyword, jReplaceKW.getText()));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //scroll to first keyword occurrence
        try {
            Rectangle rectangle = jTextArea.modelToView(pos);
            jTextArea.scrollRectToVisible(rectangle);
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```